# How to place v-text-field error message in vuetifyjs?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have `v-text-field` and I can't able to display the error message out of `v-text-field` dom position. in vuetify documentation there is not reference to this issue.

Is it possible to have the error message near the input?

Actual:

[image]

Expected:

[image]

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <playground></playground>
      <v-text-field
        style="width:120px;"
        class="numer"
        :rules="[rules.required, rules.min, rules.max]"
        v-model="numValue"
        type="number"
        append-outer-icon="add"
        @click:append-outer="increment"
        prepend-icon="remove"
        @click:prepend="decrement"
      ></v-text-field>
      {{numValue}}
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import Playground from "./components/Playground";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Playground
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      numValue: 0,
      form: {
        min: 2,
        max: 10
      },
      rules: {
        required: value => !!value || "Required.",
        min: v => v >= this.form.min || `The Min is ${this.form.min}`,
        max: v => v <= this.form.max || `The Max is ${this.form.max}`
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      if (this.numValue < this.form.max) {
        this.numValue = parseInt(this.numValue, 10) + 1;
      }
    },
    decrement() {
      if (this.numValue > this.form.min) {
        this.numValue = parseInt(this.numValue, 10) - 1;
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.numer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.numer input {
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

[The code in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-20-template-xj96d)

Answer (score -1):

I know I'm late but if someone needs help:

Put this field inside a form.

```
<v-form ref="form">
 <v-text-field
    style="width:120px;"
    class="numer"
    :rules="[rules.required, rules.min, rules.max]"
    v-model="numValue"
    type="number"
    append-outer-icon="add"
    @click:append-outer="increment"
    prepend-icon="remove"
    @click:prepend="decrement"
 ></v-text-field>
</v-form>
```

Then call anywhere on template:

```
<div @click="$refs.form.validate()">Validate it!</div>
```

Or on the functions:

```
methods: {
    foo() {
       this.$refs.form.validate()
    }
}
```